# Jibx under multimodule maven project:

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, jibx

As I do not have enough reputation to comment/answer... need to ask here.

It’s been frustrating trying to use JiBX on my project. I have the following configuration:

Maven muti-module project:

```
parent-project
 +—— model-project     This project will have the common domain objects defined on XSD files
 +—— message-project   This project will contain the Webservice Request/Response definitions on XSD and logic
 +—— backend-project    
 +—— frontend-project
```

the thing is:

on model-project I have let’s say: person.xsd is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.myexample.com/schemas/app/person" 
    xmlns:per=“http://www.myexample.com/schemas/app/person">

    <xsd:complexType name=“person">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name=“id"        type="xsd:long"     minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name=“firstName" type=“xsd:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name=“lastName"  type="xsd:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name=“dob"       type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name=“age"       type="xsd:int"      minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

and under message-project I have let’s say: personService.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified” 
    xmlns:per=“http://www.myexample.com/schemas/app/personService"
    targetNamespace="http://www.myexample.com/schemas/app/personService">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.myexample.com/schemas/app/personService" />

    <xsd:complexType name=“getPersonRequest">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name=“id" type="xsd:long" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name=“getPersonResponse">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name=“person” type=“per:person” minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

If I were using JAXB I would be able to use oasis catalogs to reference the external xsd: from message-project to the stored under model-project
but I have not been able to find something equivalent for JiBX.

I have been reading the JiBX customizations but seems not to be the right path, neither the multi-module configuration, as I am not facing a binding issue (yet) I just need to generate the service classes that references the Person object from the model-project

**Update:**

Finally I was able to generate the java source code with the desired references to module-package using JiBX customizations and maven copy files.

The only problem that now I am facing is that both modules model-project and message-project are generating the person object.

Let's say that 
   model-project generates com.example.model.Person

and 
   message-project generates 
      com.example.message.GetPersonRequest
      com.example.message.GetPersonResponse

clases were generated.

Now message-project is also generating
      com.example.model.Person
(after fixing with JiBX customization before was com.example.message.Person)
the thing is, I don't want that class and package to be generated under message-project.

So let's see if anyone can help on that.

Thanks,

-Martin

Comment: Finally I was able to generate the java source code with the desired references to module-package using JiBX customizations and maven copy files.

Comment: The more I use JiBX the more I hate it... how is that possible that when generating code from XSD, and fomr XSD have reference to other XSD which generates code in a different java package, let's say my XSD generates code in com.example.myapp.code I have a reference to another XSD which generates code in org.otherexample.theirapp.theircode the binding.xml property package is empty and the JiBX_bindingFactory class is located at the root of the classpath...

Comment: ... so JiBX_bindingFactory has no package, but the crappy spring framework Marshaller for JiBX does not accept null or empty packages, If I configure the targetPackage property with empty value, it creates a reference to .JiBX_bindingFactory but if I use a null definition (not declaring targetPackage) it will blow up an exception because I have to use either targetClass or targetPackage. but the targetClass accept only a single class, so that mean I need to create a marshaller reference for each class I want to marshall/unmarshall